# Did liquid helium help the solar system to form by cooling the nebula that collapsed to form it?

Tags: solar-system, planetary-formation, thermodynamics, helium, nebulae

Was the gas cloud that collapsed to form the solar system cooled by liquid helium at some point in time? I ask because the Cosmic microwave background had a temperature around 3K when the solar system formed and helium is a liquid at around this temperature and if the pressure is 1 atmosphere and it absorbs heat well

Comment: Nothing is liquid out there in space. The temperature of the radiation of the cosmic microwave background is not the temperature of the gas or dust in the disc.

Comment: 4.6 billion years ago corresponds to a redshift of about 0.45, so the CMB would have been $T_0(1+z) \simeq 4$ K.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the pressure was never close to 1 atmosphere and the nebula that condensed into the solar system was hotter than 3 K.

The surface density of the protoplanetary disk was [maximally about 4.3 kg per square centimeter](https://homepages.dias.ie/gallagpt/lectures/PY4A03/pdfs/PY4A03_lecture3_min_mass.ppt.pdf)... but [the thickness was about 0.2 AU](https://homepages.dias.ie/gallagpt/lectures/PY4A03/pdfs/PY4A03_lecture4_protoplanetary_disk.ppt.pdf), giving a gas density of $10^{-7}$ kg per cubic meter. Not much pressure.

[The temperature of the outer disk is believed to have been 50-150 K](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/abs/10.1146/annurev.earth.26.1.53), too warm for liquid helium.

Comment: The temperature and pressure in an undisturbed nebula may have been unsuitable but suppose a supernova  caused a low temperature cavity into which compressed gas was ejected.Then the conditions may have been suitable  There are exoplanets that have been found surrounded by helium "Helium Detected in Atmosphere of Exoplanet for First Time | Astronomy | Sci-News.com" https://www.sci.news/astronomy/wasp-107b-helium-05969.html. The helium extends 16000 km  and more above the planet

Comment: @DaveTheWave - Supernovas produce high temperature cavities.

Comment: Rapidly expanding gases cause cooling by other mechanisms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boomerang_Nebula     Is 1K temperature. Here is why. "We Finally Know why the Boomerang Nebula is Colder than Space Itself - Universe Today" universetoday.com/135920/

Comment: https://www.universetoday.com/135920/finally-know-boomerang-nebula-colder-space/.   Link for previous comment